# Jenkins does not show variables output in ECHO request in the groovy-pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, conditional-statements

just for example. I have this part of code in groovy-pipeline:

```
                echo "${GIT_BRANCH}"

                if ("${GIT_BRANCH}" == 'origin/mysuperbranch') {
                    echo 'Branch name is "${GIT_BRANCH}". We can continue'
                } else {
                    echo 'Branch name is "${GIT_BRANCH}". We can not continue'
                    isValid = false
                    return true
                }
```

And let's look on output:

```
[Pipeline] echo
origin/mysuperbranch
[Pipeline] echo
Branch name is "${GIT_BRANCH}". We can continue
```

Why in first output i can see what is in the variable `${GIT_BRANCH}`, but in the next output, i see only `${GIT_BRANCH}`. Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refering to the [String Interpolation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) you are writing the variable as string to the console. You have to remove the `"` from the variable and use them on the whole command to recognize variables.

```
echo "Branch name is ${GIT_BRANCH}. We can not continue"
```